# Why the subclass "TwoButtons" of JPanel didn't display on screen

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

It's my first post on StackOverflow. I'm a beginner in Java and I'm reading Head First Java recently. I have searched google for many times but I still can't find an answer to fix my doubt.
On chapter 12, I copy the code to Eclipse. My codes are executable, but after I click the button to change color of the circle, there's no any circle showed on the window. And another class "SimpleAnimation" has the same problem too. There is no any circle on the window. It has bothered me for two days. Please help this poor kid(TAT). Thanks!
[Run TwoButtons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRMvV.png)
Here are the codes.
This is class TwoButtons:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TwoButtons {
JFrame frame;
JLabel label;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TwoButtons gui = new TwoButtons();
    gui.go();
}

public void go() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JButton labelButton = new JButton("Change label");
    labelButton.addActionListener(new LabelListener());

    JButton colorButton = new JButton("Change circle");
    colorButton.addActionListener(new ColorListener());

    label = new JLabel("I'm a label");
    MyDrawPanel drawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, colorButton);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, labelButton);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, label);

    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

class LabelListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        label.setText("Ouch!");
    }
}

class ColorListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        frame.repaint();
    }
}

}
```

This is class MydrawPanel:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {

public void paintConponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    Color startColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

    red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    Color endColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

    GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(70, 70, startColor, 150, 150, endColor);
    g2d.setPaint(gradient);
    g2d.fillOval(70, 70, 100, 100);
}
}
```

[Run SimpleAnimation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0gpG.png)
This is class SimpleAnimation:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SimpleAnimation {
int x = 70;
int y = 70;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleAnimation gui = new SimpleAnimation();
    gui.go();
}

public void go() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    MyDrawPanel drawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();

    frame.getContentPane().add(drawPanel);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    for(int i = 0; i < 130; i++) {

        x++;
        y++;

        drawPanel.repaint();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch(Exception ex) {

        }
    }
}

class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel{
    public void paintConponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 40, 40);
    }
}
}
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters:

```
public void paintConponent(Graphics g) {
```

Should be:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
```

Always use `@Override` notation when changing methods, to ensure the method name is spelled correctly and uses the correct method arguments. Or to put that another way, use the compiler flag to check that code is actually overriding a parent method, rather than defining a new one!

### Other tips

Any custom painted component should:

1. Call the `super` method before custom painting, to ensure that older paints are erased & the BG color (etc.) of the component is painted.
2. Override the `getPreferredSize()` method to provide a hint to the layout manager.

Answer (score 0):

You have not overridden the `paintComponent` method. There is a typo in the name. Please note the `M` in `paintComponent`. Your method, in each case, is named `paintConponent`.

The compiler will warn you if you try to override a method from a superclass but get the method signature wrong (the name or the number and types of parameters) if you use the `@Override` annotation on your method:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // . . .
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the annulation override

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        Color startColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

        red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        Color endColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

        GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(70, 70, startColor, 150, 150, endColor);
        g2d.setPaint(gradient);
        g2d.fillOval(70, 70, 100, 100);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Annulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulation) doesn't mean what you seem to think it means, and this has already been covered better, twice, in other answers.